# Access Custom Property in CSSProperties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `CSSProperties` style property. I would like to access a custom property as an indexer. Not having any luck.

```
style: {
   '--primary-color': '#ff0000',
   color: '#ff0000',
} as React.CSSProperties
```

This works:

`console.log(style['color'])`

This does not:

`console.log(style['--primary-color'])`

nor does this:

`console.log(style['var(--primary-color)'])`

Error is:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"var(--primary-color)"' can't be used to index type 'CSSProperties'.
  Property 'var(--primary-color)' does not exist on type 'CSSProperties'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, even [satisfies](https://tsplay.dev/ND2x1W) doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since even [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) in 4.9+ doesn't work (gives same error as without), I suppose the only canonical solution now is to use a generic function:

```
const STYLE = <T extends React.CSSProperties>(t: T) => t;
```

It'll still check if it matches CSSProperties, and you can add in other properties, but it's a little longer:

```
const obj = {
    style: STYLE({
        "--primary-color": "#ff0000",
        color: "#ff0000",
    }),
};

obj.style["--primary-color"];
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0nprw)